# How to run Jmeter Behind company proxy?

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to use Jmeter behind Company proxy but I am not able to do that.
I have tried following solutions-
Adding Proxy settings via command line
Adding proxy settings via system.properties file
Adding proxy settings in HTTP request in Jmeter in advanced option

None of these solutions worked for me. Is there any solution which I can try?

Answer (score 0):

There are no other ways of setting the [upstream proxy for JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server), you need to figure out what's wrong with your current setup.

Take a look at [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) and look for any suspicious entries. It might be also a good idea to [increase JMeter logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) for the [HTTP protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http" level="debug" />
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick up the change.